# Using Pooling Layers in an LSTM Autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder

I am attempting to create an LSTM denoising autoencoder for use on long time series (100,000+ points) in Python using Tensorflow. I have shied away from the typical LSTM Autoencoder structure, where the information is rolled up into a single vector at the final time step and then fed into the decoder. The reason I have avoided this is that to achieve a sensible compression ratio in the encoding many neurons would be required in the final encoding layer.

My architecture uses max pooling layers after each LSTM layer to spread the compression across series length and number of neurons. The encoded representation is then taken to be the series of vectors outputted by the final layer of the encoder, not just the final vector. I have been training the model using the Adam optimiser. This architecture is perhaps better explained by the following code.

```
series_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2**14, 64), name='series_input')

x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional( tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(4)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional( tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))(x)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(4)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional( tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))(encoded)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(4)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional( tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(4)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional( tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))(x)

decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)

autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[series_input], outputs=[decoded])

autoencoder.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3,
                                                     clipvalue=10,
                                                     decay=0.005),
                        loss='mean_squared_error',
                        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My initial attempts at training the model seem to show that it is a viable architecture, and able to learn sensible denoising strategies. The problem, however, is that this configuration drastically slows the training process. To add some colour, it trains significantly more slowly than other stacked LSTM structures—a variation on this architecture took around a day to complete a single epoch when running on 4 V100s. What is the reason for this? What could be done to improve the computational efficiency of this model? I am open to any suggestions and happy to hear them. Thank you for taking the time to reach the end of this post.

Comment: Have you tried CuDNNLSTM? It's quite fast and can be used as a drop-in replacement for LSTM. But it doesn't support dropout regularization and the activation function cannot also be modified, so it's not widely used.

Comment: The inflexibility of these units put me off using them, but on your recommendation I replaced the existing LSTM units. The swap has provided the required speed boost—thank you! I will happily accept this answer if you decide to write it up.